# Como enviar apenas uma vez um formulário a cada 5 minutos

Tags: php, javascript

Bom, eu queria saber, como eu poderia fazer com que a pessoa envie formulário apenas no intervalo de 5 minutos.

```
<?php
    $nome  = $_POST["nome"];
$locutor = $_POST["locutor"];
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$coment = "INSERT INTO `pedidos` ( `nome` , `locutor` , `texto`, `data` , `id`, `num` ) VALUES ('$nome', '$locutor', '$texto', now(), '', '')";

mysql_query($coment);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar a [*session*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) para guardar dados sobre a sessão de um dado utilizador.

Um exemplo simples poderia ser assim:

```
session_start();
$date = new DateTime();
$now = $date->getTimestamp();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ultimo_timestamp'])) {
  $_SESSION['ultimo_timestamp'] = $now;
} else {
  if($now - $_SESSION['ultimo_timestamp'] < 5 * 60) die('Ainda não passaram 5 minutos...');
  else $_SESSION['ultimo_timestamp'] = $now;
}
```

Desta maneira guardas no objeto `$_SESSION` o timestamp (em segundos) desde o ultimo envio do formulário e dás uma mensagem caso ainda não tenha passado 5 minutos.

Comment: Mas esse php eu coloco junto com o insert?

Comment: @Kloves deves colocar antes do INSERT pois este código pára a execução caso não tenham passado 5 mimutos. Estou a assumir que essa página PHP só tem o código para fazer o insert.

Comment: Aí no caso eu coloco um "else" e boto o insert dentro?